# Create regex to select different items

Tags: regex

I have three types of URLs. I am trying to create regex to select each type of URL. Let's say three types of URLs are :-

First One :- http://www.domain.com/goodday/

Second One :- http://www.domain.com/today-is-gooddady/

Third One :- http://www.domain.com/life-is-good/enjoy-a-happy-life/

Now, I need different regex for each of them. I am using this :-

`http://www.domain.com/(.*?)/`   But it is selecting all of them. I need three regex to select three type of URLs.

Comment: In order to receive a helpful answer, please try to give a more exact specification of your problem. What is the difference between your three types of URLs? Your examples leave the reader guessing. Is it the number of slashes and dashes? String length? The number of "d"s following the string "good"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, bear in mind that a dot inside  a regex pattern must be escaped to match a literal dot, or it will match any character (but a newline).

Assuming the first URL has no hyphens and contains only one subpart after the base part:

```
^http://www\.domain\.com/[^/-]*/$
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/zR9uR5/2)

The second one can be matched with

```
^http://www\.domain\.com/[^/-]+(?:-[^/-]+)+/$
```

if the point is that the only subpart after base part should have at least 1 hyphen. See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/zR9uR5/4)

And the third one, assuming there must be 2 subparts, can be matched with

```
^http://www\.domain\.com/[^/]+/[^/]+/$
```

See [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/zR9uR5/5)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understood you correctly:
1st only : `http:\/\/www.domain.com\/[^-]*?\/$` 
2nd only : `http:\/\/www.domain.com\/[^\/]*?\/$`
3rd only : `http:\/\/www.domain.com\/[^\/]*?\/[^\/]*?\/$`